# Как вывести параметры категории из бд

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Из фронтенда решил перейти в бэкенд, подскажите пожалуйста, как происходит вывод данных выбранной категории, единственный момент который понять не могу... Вот к примеру, у меня есть таблица в бд категорий, там поля id, title и тд, как мне вывести title выбранной категории. Нужно передать id и по нем как то вытянуть title? Если можно покажите пример,пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

sql запрос
SELECT title FROM yourTable WHERE id = yourID

меняешь "youTable" на название своей таблицы и "yourID" на ид категории которую нужно взять с БД.

Comment: Вы не поняли. У меня есть меню категорий. Допустим перехожу я по ссылке в категорию "Велосипеды". Нужно что бы когда я перешел в эту категорию у меня были все данные на страницы этой категории, то-есть нужен скорее всего тут GET запрос

Comment: Ну тогда у вас должна быть ещё таблица товаров. У которой к каждому товару есть поле например id_cat, которое хранит в себе id нужной категории.

Comment: После чего переходите в категорию например велосипеды (пусть это id = 1), этот айди передаёте через гет, ловите этот параметр $_GET['id'], и делаете выборку с базы товаров где id_cat=$_GET['id']

Comment: Или у вас все в одной таблице ?